# Improve algorithm to scale chart axis limits appropriately based on the chart data

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I made this subroutine a while ago as I was dissatisfied with Excel's auto-scaling for charts. The built-in Excel method works to an extent but when the range of the chart data gets a bit wider it just sets the minimum scale to 0 which can result in very squished lines with loads of blank space beneath it. Like below...

[image: Inappropriately scaled Chart]

The code I wrote attempts to improve on excel's method by choosing a suitable max and min limit for the y-axis based on the data in the chart. It works OK but sometimes chooses not-the-best values. Here is the result from my code applied to the same chart:

[image: Inappropriately scaled Chart]

Here it has fit all the data in the plot area so it is quite clear to see but the values it chose aren't the best. A human can look at this data and quickly assess that 90 and 140 are probably the best limits to use in this example but I've had trouble writing a script to do the same.

Here is the entire sub. It's not too long. I'd appreciate any suggestions to improve the calculation of the limits...

```
Sub ScaleCharts()
'
' ScaleCharts Macro
'
Dim objCht As ChartObject
Dim maxi As Double, mini As Double, Range As Double, Adj As Double, xMax As Double, xMin As Double
Dim Round As Integer, Order As Integer, x As Integer, i As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For x = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
Application.StatusBar = "Crunching sheet " & x & " of " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count

For Each objCht In Sheets(x).ChartObjects
  If objCht.Chart.ChartType = xlLine Or objCht.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatter Then
  With objCht.Chart
  For i = 0 To .SeriesCollection.Count - 1 'Loop through all the series in the chart

            'Get the Max and Min values of the data in the chart
            maxi = Application.max(.SeriesCollection(i + 1).Values)
            mini = Application.min(.SeriesCollection(i + 1).Values)
            Range = maxi - mini

            If Range > 1 Then
                Order = Len(Int(Range))
                Adj = 10 ^ (Order - 2)
                Round = -1 * (Order - 1)
            ElseIf Range <> 0 Then
                Order = Len(Int(1 / Range))
                Adj = 10 ^ (-1 * Order)
                Round = Order - 1
            End If

            'Get the Max and Min values for the axis based on the data
            If i = 0 Or WorksheetFunction.Round(maxi, Round + 1) + Adj > xMax Then
            xMax = WorksheetFunction.Round(maxi, Round + 1) + Adj
            End If

            If i = 0 Or WorksheetFunction.Round(mini, Round + 1) - Adj < xMin Then
            xMin = WorksheetFunction.Round(mini, Round + 1) - Adj
            End If

       Next i

     With .Axes(xlValue)
        .MaximumScale = xMax
        .MinimumScale = xMin
     End With
  End With
  End If
Next objCht
Next x
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```

EDIT: Here are the results of qPCR4vir's changes...

[**Before**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpTDG.jpg)

[**After**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwiZT.jpg)

The last 2 charts get cut off as they do not exceed -100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of using what Excel calculate: MajorUnit is good (assuming is allways rigth!! need to be proof). Now the round function you are looking for is:

```
tryxMax = Sgn(maxi) * WorksheetFunction.MRound(Abs(maxi + maju / 2.001), maju)
tryxMin = Sgn(mini) * WorksheetFunction.MRound(Abs(mini - maju / 2.001), maju)
```

It work for all nummers, small or negative inclusive.

Comment: Yes your method looks the best - my previous attempt was OK but still was flawed in certain circumstances but yours looks more robust. I shall accept this as the answer (and add the entire code so as to help others). Good team effort!

Answer (score 1):

Can you test?:

```
Adj = 10 ^ (Order - 1)
```

and

```
xMax = WorksheetFunction.ROUNDDOWN(maxi + Adj, Round )
xMin = WorksheetFunction.ROUNDDOWN(mini , Round )
```

in place of:

```
Adj = 10 ^ (Order - 2)
```

and

```
xMax = WorksheetFunction.Round(maxi, Round + 1) + Adj
```

and

```
xMin = WorksheetFunction.Round(mini, Round + 1) - Adj
```

EDIT: ROUNDDOWN is incorrect for neg nummbers? We can model it with ROUND

```
xMax = WorksheetFunction.Round(maxi + Adj/2, Round )
xMin = WorksheetFunction.Round(mini - Adj/2, Round )
```

Comment: Initial testing seems to show that your changes produce much better results. I will need to try on a range of charts, including those who's values are very small as it can be hard to capture every scenario but first signs look good. Thanks

Comment: Right. I brain-debugged for >1. But I hope you got the idea and correct any problems for other values. ..And make it public- I also want to use it !!  ;-)

Comment: I just tested on charts that have values both <0 and >0. Unfortunately the negative part of the plot gets cut off as sometimes the largest negative number is not enough to decrease the xMin threshold

Comment: @harryg : ROUNDDOWN is incorrect for neg nummbers? We can model it with ROUND. See edit in answer.

Comment: OK I've just come up with a new solution - see my own answer above. Will test yours and compare

Answer (score 1):

OK I've had another go myself using the `MajorUnit` property suggested by Vicky

```
Sub ScaleCharts3()
'
' ScaleCharts Macro
'
   Call revertCharts 'A macro that resets the charts to excel auto beforehand - this is so we get the correct "MajorUnit" value

   Dim objCht As ChartObject
   Dim maxi As Double, mini As Double, tryxMax As Double, tryxMin As Double, xMax As Double, xMin As Double, maju As Double
   Dim x As Integer, i As Integer

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   For x = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
   Application.StatusBar = "Crunching sheet " & x & " of " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count

   For Each objCht In Sheets(x).ChartObjects
      If objCht.Chart.ChartType = xlLine Or objCht.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatter Then
      With objCht.Chart
      maju = .Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit
      For i = 0 To .SeriesCollection.Count - 1 'Loop through all the series in the chart

                'Get the Max and Min values of the data in the chart
                maxi = Application.max(.SeriesCollection(i + 1).Values)
                mini = Application.min(.SeriesCollection(i + 1).Values)

                'Get the Max and Min values for the axis based on the data
                tryxMax = roundToMult(maxi, maju)
                tryxMin = roundToMult(mini, maju, False)


                If i = 0 Or tryxMax > xMax Then
                xMax = tryxMax
                End If
                If i = 0 Or tryxMin < xMin Then
                xMin = tryxMin
                End If

           Next i

         With .Axes(xlValue)
            .MaximumScale = xMax
            .MinimumScale = xMin
         End With
      End With
      End If
   Next objCht
   Next x
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```

We also need a function that will round up and down to the nearest multiple accordingly as is referenced above.

```
Function roundToMult(numToRound As Double, multiple As Double, Optional up As Boolean = True)
numToRound = Int(numToRound)
multiple = Int(multiple)

If multiple = 0 Then
roundToMult = 0
Exit Function
End If

remainder = numToRound Mod multiple
If remainder = 0 Then
roundToMult = numToRound
Else
    If up = True Then
        roundToMult = (numToRound + multiple - remainder)
    Else
        If numToRound < 0 Then
            remainder = multiple + remainder
        End If
        roundToMult = (numToRound - remainder)
    End If
End If
End Function
```

There wont be any effect when used with small numbers (<1) but Excel usually scaled more appropriately automatically here. This is also tested on negative and mixed neg/pos chart data and seems to work.

Comment: Good stuff! I believe you can accept your own answer (click the outline of the green tick).

Comment: @harryg. I have an idea for this function. Look my new answer for these new problem (now a have tested it, and work).

Answer (score 0):

What is the algorithm you use as a human when you say that 90 and 140 are the best values?

Personally I would look at the axis divisions that Excel has selected by default, and pick the closest divisions that lie outside the data itself. That would give you 80 and 140 in your example.

Excel calls this the "MajorUnit" property of the Axis object.

Comment: That is my point, as humans we don't use an algorithm, we just look and judge by eye/estimation. Using the axis divisions is an OK approach but it is difficult to specify the actual min and max from this. Say my min data point is 98 I could use the axis division of 20 to try and work out the min: (`98-20 = 78`) which is still an inappropriate number to use. The difficulty is rounding the numbers appropriately.

Comment: We absolutely DO use an algorithm, it's just somewhere in our subconscious and may include heuristics and fuzzy logic.

Comment: Also if the axis division is 20, find the nearest multiple of 20 = 80.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the approach I use:
[Calculate Nice Axis Scales in Excel VBA](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/calculate-nice-axis-scales-in-excel-vba/)